# Play framework 2.0.4 select box sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scala, playframework-2.0

I am currently implementing a UI in play 2.0.4, but I am having problems with the @select helper that I am using for creating a select box. I bind the select to the method Test.methodName which returns a Map object that contains data in the following format:

    {2=Sorted1, 1=Sorted2}
As can be seen the data are sorted by their value, and I want this order to be saved when the elements are listed in the select. However, the items are listed in the following order in the select:

```
Sorted2
Sorted1
```

It seems like data are sorted by their key. How can I sort by value in the select?

```
@select(
            paramForm("standardDbName"), 
            options = options(Test.methodName),
            'id -> "standardDb",
            '_default -> "--- Choose DB ---",
            '_label -> "Database Name",
            '_error -> paramForm("standardDbName").error.map(_.withMessage(""))
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

If are you using java use LinkedHashMap instead of Map.

Comment: The question is tagged as scala

Comment: @maxmc You are right. The answer still helped me out in Java, as unfortunately the documentation of the playframework is missing so much essential details... :(

Answer (score 1):

The nature of a map is that it's not sorted. You could return a Seq of Tuples `Seq("test"-> 1, "test2" -> 2)` instead of a map.